# Using PERL compatible regular expressions to ignore the string case in a query

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, perl

I'm using [Parse](http://parse.com) as the backend for my iOS app (they add their own framework to the project adding methods for use with their database). Its a simple database that includes a column with the names of the files I stored. Right now, when I query using their `containsString` method, which only returns results with matching cases for every letter. So searching for "john" will NOT return "John". But they do have the option of using a `matchesRegex` method that allows for regular expressions input. I want to know how I can use regex to say that the result should contain my input string, but needs to ignore its case? So if I search for "john", it will match it with "John", "JOHN", etc.

So it would look something like:

```
[query whereKey:@"file_name" matchesRegex:@"something_that_returns_all_johns"];
```

They use PERL compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PCREs, you can mark just part of a regex as case-insensitive by wrapping it in `(?i:...)` or preceding it with `(?i)`. Usually there's a separate, out-of-band way to indicate that the *whole* regex is case-insensitive, but if the Parse API doesn't offer such a way, then you can just apply the part-of-the-regex approach to the whole regex, using either of these:

```
[query whereKey:@"file_name" matchesRegex:@"(?i:john)"];
[query whereKey:@"file_name" matchesRegex:@"(?i)john"];
```

(assuming that Parse supports these features of PCREs: it probably does).

Comment: Tried the second one and it worked great. Thanks!

I tried adding a /i at the end but that didnt work.